# Grey out tray icon in Swift on click.

Tags: macos, swift, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have created a simple tray application which is doing background checks. I have added a submenu to the tray application. I want the Icon of the tray application to be greyed out when I click the "Stop" item of the Menu.

With `statusItem.enabled = false;` i can grey out the tray icon but I am also disabling the whole application.

Is there any other possibility to grey out the icon or will i have to add another icon and change the icon on click??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. Two icons are needed

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)
let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
let iconGrey = NSImage(named: "statusIconGrey")
```

Then you just have to change it to whatever you like

```
statusItem.image = icon
statusItem.menu = statusMenu
```

or

```
statusItem.image = iconGrey
statusItem.menu = statusMenu
```